# UILabel - Display ... when text length crosses certain length

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uilabel

I have placed `UILabel` in my application, in that I want to display the text with .... once the length of the text exceeds the certain count.

Because if the text goes longer, it gives the design issue.

Please let know which function to use.

Comment: so do you want to increase height and width of that label according to that character ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

If you are adding your UILabel from interface builder you can do it directly. **Select** you UILabel and in the **Utilities** column in **Attriubtes Inspector**=> **Label** section=> **Line Breaks** set **Truncate Tail**

Comment: You can also set the line break mode in the NIB, if you're using a NIB.

Comment: @robmayoff ya as you mentioned it, I have showed in my answer how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Try this will helpful for you.

```
NSString *string=YourString;

int size=[YourString length];

if (size>21) 
{
    NSMutableString *string1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    char c;
    for(int index = 0;index <20 ;index++)
    {
        c =[string characterAtIndex:index];

        [string1 appendFormat:@"%c",c];
    }
    [string1 appendFormat:@"..."];
    string=string1;

}
```

Add "string" on your UILable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define EXCEEDED_LENGTH 8

- (NSString *) checkStringLength:(NSString *)str 
{
    if(str.length >= EXCEEDED_LENGTH) 
    {
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",[str subStringToIndex:EXCEEDED_LENGTH-1]];
    }
    return str;
}

yourLabel.text = [self checkStringLength:@"Hello World !!"];
```

Output like `Hello Wo...` For better output you can `trim` `whitespaces` before pass string to function.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can make `UILable` size(length/width) Dynamic,

Or

You can `UITextView` with edit disable so if there will be long text it will be scrollable.

Comment: Also you can use sizeToFit and sizeThatFits, this may also solve your problem upto some extend.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you shared I think the `autoshrink` and `linebreakermode` may be the root cause.IT is the property which tries to show the contents in the specified frame which will decrease and adjust the font size

2 ways to sove the issue

- adjust the property according to requirement
- Increase the framesize of label(programmatically by finding size)
- also look on the edge insets

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(690.0, 2000.0);
CGSize size_txt_overview1 = [[headItemArray objectAtIndex:k] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
UILabel *lbl_headitem = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,h, 690, size_txt_overview1.height)];
lbl_headitem.numberOfLines=0;
```

Please set your `UILabel` width and height in `CGSize` constraint. Best way.. and it worked for me.

Comment: Please Ensure that Yourlabel.numberOfLines=0;

Answer (score 0):

This is a method for a Category of UILabel

```
-(void)setTruncatedTextWithDotsIfNeeded:(NSString *)text
    {
        float fullTextWidth = [text sizeWithFont:self.font].width;
        float labelWidth = self.frame.size.width;
        if(fullTextWidth<=labelWidth){
            [self setText:text];
            return;
        }
        NSString *dots = @"…";
        float dotsWidth = [dots sizeWithFont:self.font].width;
        NSRange fullRange = [text rangeOfString:text];
        for(int i = fullRange.length; i >= fullRange.location; i--){
            NSRange currentRange;
            currentRange.location = 0;
            currentRange.length = i;
            NSString *partialText = [text substringWithRange:currentRange];
            float partialTextWidth = [partialText sizeWithFont:self.font].width;
            if(partialTextWidth + dotsWidth <= labelWidth){
                [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",partialText]];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```